# How can I quickly and cleanly kill a print job?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, printing

On occasion, I've tried to kill a print job started in error, to avoid a waste of paper and toner. I know there are several layers to the printing system in use, and the GUI printer queue applet is not particularly responsive. What's the quickest way to kill and purge a print job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the command line?

```
lpstat -o|more
```

will show a list of pid numbers and then...

```
cancel {pid number}
```

You might need to turn the printer of to have the printer cancel what is already in its memory.

Answer (score 4):

Try opening cups in a browser window (localhost:631) and cancelling from there.